# google map in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I am loading iframe using following line as show in image. I am getting the following error. How to resolve it 
[image]

```
this.mapUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+this._auctionDetails.AuctionDetail.Latitude +","+this._auctionDetails.AuctionDetail.Longitude+"&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed";
```

When page is loaded it gives me error. Here is my i frame code in html. I am using pipe.

```
<iframe [src]="mapUrl | safe" width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use your iframe like this.

```
this.mapUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={{API-KEY}}&q="+this._auctionDetails.AuctionDetail.Latitude +","+this._auctionDetails.AuctionDetail.Longitude+"";
```

Then it will load perfectly. Rest of code is okay. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Late Comer but maybe it will help someone. Try to enable the embed API from the google maps API dashboard. It solves the issue for me.